# Config.php File Not Working Properly with dirname(__FILE__)

Tags: php, config, dirname

My config file looks like this:

```
<?php
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(_FILE_));
?>
```

then my html:

```
<?php 
require_once ('../../../../config.php');  // back to app root
?>

<?php
$pageTitle = 'title';
require_once(ROOT_DIR.'includes/content.php');
?>
```

I know my config file is loading because I can see my config comments when I view source.

But, otherwise I'm just getting a blank page. Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

## EDIT:

**Error Reporting yields**

```
Warning: require_once(./includes/content.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/html/BLX2012/prototypes/19/demo.16/events/2013/PIC/LasVegas/index.php on line 10

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required './includes/content.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/html/BLX2012/prototypes/19/demo.16/events/2013/PIC/LasVegas/index.php on line 10
```

[Sorry I wish the above were more readble]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_FILE_` should be `__FILE__` (2 underscores on each side).

So your `ROOT_DIR` constant is being set wrong, and PHP doesn't know where to look.

Comment: wow, ok the things I miss. Being a newb, had no idea there were [2] on each side. FIXED, thank you! And thnx guys for giving me some love! `:]`

Comment: @conceive No probs, glad to be of service :) There's plenty of times I've made that kind of mistake, even after coding PHP professionally for 7 years!

Answer (score 2):

you're missing a `/` in: `require_once(ROOT_DIR.'includes/content.php');`

Change it to:
`require_once(ROOT_DIR.'/includes/content.php');`

Comment: Really? I just tried that- still not working. I never used a leading `/` before when using `include()`. What am I missing?

Comment: @Populus- Actually, you were also correct that I needed a leading `/` in my file references. I'm not sure why this is the case s ince I've never used them for my regular `include()` calls. Thx for your help!! `:]`

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of your script, add this statement to see if you get any errors:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Is it possible that `content.php` includes a file in a wrong path?

Comment: @Simon- no the paths seem correct. Yea, I used `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
`

Comment: It clearly says the file (`content.php`) doesn't exist is the path for that correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct actually. I just don't understand what I'm missing. Because it's in the right place in theory. Gotta check again, thx...